# How to add different information in GridView.builder cads?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add diferent information in the cards that I created with a GridView.builder, what I am trying to achieve is not having to hard code all the information, but that it renders in a non static way.

I will attach the code here:

```
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 350.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white54,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                )
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 250.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                  )
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: 8,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, size: 18.0,),
                          Text('Hobbies'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),),
              ),
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to take info from and how does it stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, if you want to display only 8 cards I would also try going with a simple GridView and no .builder  :) That's because you don't really need the optimization GridView.builder provides you if you have so few items.

Anyway! This is what I did:

1- I've created a dummy list of "names"  to contain my "data":

```
  final List<String> names = [
"Mark",
"Lorenzo",
"Henry",
"Kevin",
"Isabelle",
"Mary",
"Dalia",
"Stella",];
```

2- I've passed my names list to itembuilder, using "index" to point at the different String contained inside my List.

```
child: GridView.builder(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
    itemCount: names.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
      return new Card(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(
                Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                size: 18.0,
              ),
              Text(names[index]),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
    gridDelegate:
        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
  ),
```

I'd suggest you in case you have a List of objects not to hardcode it's number into itemCount but instead using listname.size as I did above :)
Ofc this is a very basic example to show you how it's done, for complex (or server side/more dynamic) data I suggest you store that into their own class!

I'm quite new at Flutter (and coding) too but I hope I provided some help and, more importantly, a correct answer.